# Vuejs2 passing dynamic data within data

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

Am trying to save an invoice template html code to mysql database and later load it in vue and add properties to the data from mysql

SO this is what i mean

Suppose i have the followig template

```
<div>
 <h1>Medical certificate</h1>
 <h2>{{userame}}</h2>

 <div>
```

So am saving the above html code in mysql and fetching it and now i would like to inject the value of username using vuejs2

SO that is

```
data:()=>({
 username:'testuser',
 html_template:''
 }),

 methods:{
   getTemplateFromHtml(){
    this.$http.get('')
      .then((res)=>{this.html_template = res.data})

   }

  }
```

SO in template part i have

```
<template>
   <div v-html="html_template"></div>
<div>
```

Now the problem comes in when injecting the value of username to the rendered html code(from mysql). THe value of username is never passed. How do i go on about this?

Comment: Checkout vue runtime templates https://github.com/alexjoverm/v-runtime-template

Comment: @Mehari thanks exactly what am looking for

Comment: @Mehari  surely done

Comment: There's also this fiddle that I think is relevant https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/1zdzu7k1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You are looking for [**v-runtime-template**](https://github.com/alexjoverm/v-runtime-template)

```
<template>
  <div>
        <v-runtime-template :template="html_template"></v-runtime-template>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import VRuntimeTemplate from "v-runtime-template";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data: () => ({
    username: "testuser",
    html_template: `
    <div>
      <h1>Medical certificate</h1>
      <h2>{{username}}</h2>
    <div>
    `
  }),
  components: {
    VRuntimeTemplate
  }
};
</script>
```

Here is a [**sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/n0j1r6pk6p)